# consumme a webservice by REST with authentication in full javaScript

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication

I would like to consumme a webservice in REST, in full javaScript. It is not really difficult as we need to use xmlHttRequest, Ajax,etc.

My issue is that I don't understand how to use the login and the password. I read a lot of comments (token, http...) but there is no example of code. Can someone post a code in javascript?

I found this usefull link but there is no code in cas of you have to provide a login and password?

[Example Rest service in full javaScript](http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-javascript.html)

Comment: This in not correct way to ask a question. You should try by yourself and if you had problem or technical issue share it with good explain and some code snippet and in this way you can get good answers and improve knowledge sharing.

Comment: Does your REST service has some authentication? If it does, please include some code snippet or at least explanation. After that you may get usable answers.

Comment: Hi all, thank you for your reply. @QMaster, I would be happy to try if I have an example of code to consume REST service with Authentication. REST is quitely easy. It is only Ajax. It is not the issue. What I found on the web is some explanations concerning the interest of authentication. Useless without example to post data with username/password. Regards

Comment: @Buthtla, I would try and let you know. The issue is to send you some code I need to find a global REST service so that you can test from your side with authencation, as I can't provide you my personal account. I will check and let you know.

Comment: @AdamEve my experience is the irregular Technics can't got good answers most of times specially when you didn't have a base approach generated by yourself and you can find it by answers this question don't have. Anyway hope you find proper way to solve it. Best Wishes.

Answer (score 1):

thank you for your help. I found the solution. You have to add in the header X-WSSE and you have to generate a digest password. it is the more difficult part.

Hope it is helpful.

regards